# Maximize exposure and sharpness

Tags: macos, preview

I often print pages from photos taken from books. When I do this I open the jpeg file in Preview on macOS and maximize exposure and sharpness from the "Adjust Color" panel. Is there a way to automate this for many files (app maybe)?

Comment: When you “maximize”  exposure and/or sharpness, how do you know you’re not over exposing (washing out) your image or increasing noise, respectively?

Comment: I use the notes app to scan pages form a book, then choose the “Black & White” filter, then run it through a PDF to PNG converter. This gives a very clean image, better than what I can get from a photo editing app.

Comment: Lots of photo apps allow you to edit many photos at once. Some allow you edit one and then apply those changes to multiple photos. Some allow you to actually apply some automated process to multiple photos. If you're doing this a lot, you might want to consider capturing your images using a “scanning” app, as they do a lot of the automated color related adjustments for you. Capturing the image in an app that assumes it is a document eliminates a lot of this hassle for you.